Why would retrieving the angel from the volcano risk another Second Impact?
In episode 10 of Neon Genesis Evangelion, the Evangelions are sent into a volcano to capture a baby angel. The mission is repeatedly described as having a risk of eradicating humanity if something goes wrong.

Committee member: A-17?! We're going on the offensive?
Gendou: Correct.
Committee member: It's too dangerous. Don't pretend you've forgotten what happened 15 years ago.
Gendou: This is a golden opportunity. We can finally take the fight to them, rather than remain on the defensive.
Kirl: The risk is too great.
Gendou: This is a living Angel specimen. I needn't stress the significance of that.
Kirl: Failure will not be tolerated.
Fuyuzuki: Failure? Failure would mean the extinction of humanity.

...

Ritsuko: You've been afraid of the today's operation?
Misato: Well, yes. if wrongly done, another that..
Ritsuko: Yes. second impact... I don't want that again.

- Transcript from Forever Dreaming and Animanga
Why is this mission considered so much riskier than the other fights against angels? Wouldn't failure mean the extinction of humanity for any angel attacks?
